# jQuery: save position of divs which are inside two sortable divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I want to save the position of the div-boxes inside the sortable left-div/right-div. PS: I use the jquery-cookie plugin.

**With position, I mean:**

- Whether the item (like `#module_weather` or `#module_news`) is in the left or right div
- In which order the items (like `#module_weather` or `#module_news`) are, for example in the left div: at first `#module_weather` and then `#module_news`

[image]
**Javascript (jQuery)**

```
$( ".padding_10px" ).sortable({
    handle: ".panelheadbar",
    helper: "clone",
    appendTo: ".content",
    connectWith: ".left, .right"
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="content_left">
        <div class="padding_10px left">
            <div id="module_weather" class="panelgroup">
                <div class="panelheadbar">Weather</div>
                <div id="pc_weather" class="panelcontent">
                    text here...
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="module_news" class="panelgroup">
                <div class="panelheadbar">News</div>
                <div id="pc_news" class="panelcontent">
                    text here...
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content_mid">
        not interesting here...
    </div>
    <div class="content_right">
        <div class="padding_10px right">
            <div id="module_changelogs" class="panelgroup">
                <div class="panelheadbar">Changelogs</div>
                <div id="pc_changelogs" class="panelcontent">
                    text here...
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="module_dontknow" class="panelgroup">
                <div class="panelheadbar">Dontknow</div>
                <div id="pc_dontknow" class="panelcontent">
                    text here...
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I save the position in a cookie and how can I read the cookie so that the items are listed in the right div and the right order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about something like below. Each element and the containers need unique ids.

```
function savePosition(id){
    var el = $("#" + id);
    var container = el.parent().attr("id");
    var index = el.index();
    $.cookie(id,JSON.stringify({ container:container, index:index }));
}
function loadPosition(id){
    var el = $("#" + id);
    var position = JSON.parse($.cookie(id));
    var container = "#" + position.container;
    var index = position.index;
    if(index == 0){
        $(container).prepend(el);
    }else if($(container).children().eq(index - 1).length == 0){
        $(container).append(el);
    }else{
        $(container).children().eq(index - 1).after(el);
    }        
}
```

**UPDATE**

To address your comment, you probably need to iterate over each element every time you need to save/load.

To save:

```
$("#left,#right").children().each(function(){
    savePosition($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

To load:

```
$("#left,#right").children().each(function(){
    loadPosition($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

**UPDATE 2**

Fixed a bug with the code above. Changed `$(container).eq(...)` to `$(container).children().eq(..)` Here's your updated jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/be0Lmu4j/4/

Also, as per your comments, here's an update event for the sortable method:

```
$( ".padding_10px" ).sortable({
    handle: ".panelheadbar",
    helper: "clone",
    appendTo: ".content",
    connectWith: ".left, .right",
    update:function(){
        $("#left,#right").children().each(function(){
            savePosition($(this).attr("id"));
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: How can I get the id of the child which I've dragged somewhere? I had the idea to put your function to the update-action of the sortable div: `$(".padding_10px").sortable({update: your function});`

Comment: You probably need to iterate over each element every time you want to save/load and get the id using `$(this).attr("id")`. See updated answer

Comment: Also this is kind of bugging me, but why use the class name `padding_10px`? What if you change how much padding that class has in the css file? Then you'll have to update the class name to `padding_Xpx`.  It's no better than putting `style='padding:10px'` everywhere and kind of defeats the purpose of a stylesheet.

Comment: I tried to include `padding: 10px` to `.content_left` but then I got the problem that my split of my website didn't work. The `.content_left`-div with a width of 25% lapped over the `.content` with lets say 75% width.

Comment: I used your code now and the browser creates cookies for each element (the cookies look like this: `%7B%22container%22%3A%22right%22%2C%22index%22%3A2%7D`. But the cookies don't change their values if I drag the boxes somewhere else (is here the update-action of sortable needed?). And when I include the load-part of your code the lowest (y-axis) box has no padding to the parent-container anymore and the lowest box isn't sortable/draggable anymore.

Comment: You need to call savePosition with the id of the element you want to save whenever you want to update the cookie. That update event would probably work, just make sure you pass the id to savePosition.  I'm not sure what's happening with the padding. It seems like it isn't getting added to the sortable container.  If you make a jsfiddle I can look at it further.

Comment: Whoops, that code has a bug. I'll update the answer with the corrections. It should be `$(container).children().eq(...)` not `$(container).eq(...)`.  I also updated your fiddle with the sortable update event that will save on rearrange here: https://jsfiddle.net/be0Lmu4j/3/

Comment: I mentioned now that I get a error in the google chrome console: `Uncaught Syntax Error: Unexpected token u`. I only get this error if your load-Code is in the code. And I only get this error if the cookies aren't created yet, because the cookies won't be created if the user doesn't change sth within the sortable (because of the update-event). Maybe I should check whether a cookie like 'module_blaBla' is created and if not, create one, but how can I do this?

Comment: Or is there any option to stop the loadPosition-function when there is no cookie?

Comment: maybe use an if statement? if cookies aren't created, create cookies for all positions

Comment: Thank you again :) That was easier than I thought